# how to stop solr in standard way within docker

Tags: apache, solr, docker

I have solr in docker with standard command line as entry point.
Thing is - if container is stopped - how do I configure the "stop" script of solr (stop functionality exits within this standard script).

Solr waits on specific port for a stop sign (-DSTOP.PORT=7983)

I'd like that for all the flush \ transactions etc.

How can this be configured?

Answer (score 0):

You could look at hooking into the lifecycle events, an example is described here:

http://blog.scoutapp.com/articles/2015/06/05/monitoring-docker-events

And there's a good diagram showing the lifecycle here, you'd want to react to the die event:

http://gliderlabs.com/blog/2015/04/14/docker-events-explained/

Not done it myself unfortunately but hopefully when the die event happens solr will still be available.